# Difference with previous data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE datos ( 
    id_estacion smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, 
    id_sensor smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, 
    tipo_sensor smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL, 
    valor float DEFAULT NULL, 
    fecha date DEFAULT NULL, 
    hora time DEFAULT NULL, 
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    dato float DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8556 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And this data:

```
id_estacion  fecha       hora      valor
1            2019-03-15  00:00:00  1164.63
1            2019-03-15  00:15:00  1164.63
1            2019-03-15  00:30:00  1164.64
1            2019-03-15  00:45:00  1164.62
1            2019-03-15  01:00:00  1164.67
1            2019-03-15  01:15:00  1164.63
1            2019-03-15  01:30:00  1164.64
```

I need to calculate with mysql the difference between a data and the previous data. For example the value at `'00:30'` is `1164.64`, the previus value, at `'00:15'`, is `1164.63` the difference is `0.01`.

```
id_estacion  fecha      hora     valor    diferencia
1            3/15/2019  0:00:00  1164.63   0
1            3/15/2019  0:15:00  1164.63   0
1            3/15/2019  0:30:00  1164.64   0.01
1            3/15/2019  0:45:00  1164.62  -0.02
1            3/15/2019  1:00:00  1164.67   0.05
1            3/15/2019  1:15:00  1164.63  -0.04
1            3/15/2019  1:30:00  1164.64   0.01
```

Is that possible? Hope you understand me.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that should work on all versions of MySQL. 
The principle is to self-`JOIN` the table, using a `NOT EXISTS` condition to bring in the previous record of the same `id_estacion`.

```
SELECT
    t.id_estacion,
    t.fetcha,
    t.hora,
    t.valor,
    COALESCE(t.valor - tprev.valor, 0) diferencia
FROM mytable t
LEFT JOIN mytable tprev 
    ON  tprev.id_estacion = t.id_estacion
    AND CONCAT(tprev.fecha, ' ', tprev.hora) < CONCAT(t.fecha, ' ', t.hora)
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM mytable t1 
        WHERE 
            t1.id_estacion = t.id_estacion 
            AND CONCAT(t1.fecha, ' ', t1.hora) < CONCAT(t.fecha, ' ', t.hora)
            AND CONCAT(t1.fecha, ' ', t1.hora) > CONCAT(tprev.fecha, ' ', tprev.hora)
    )
```

NB: I would recommend not storing the date and time parts in separated columns, as it just makes things more complex; instead, you can use a unique column of datatype `DATETIME`, and use [MySQL date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) when you need to extract parts of it.